# gsub same pattern from a string

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have big problems with figuring out how regex works.
I want this text:

`This is an example\e[213] text\e[123] for demonstration`

to become this:

```
This is an example text for demonstration.
```

So this means that I want to remove all strings that begin with `\e[` and end with `]`
I just cant find a proper regex for this.
My current regex looks like this:

```
/.*?(\\e\[.*\])?.*/ig
```

But it dont work. I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to do this:

```
txt.gsub(/\\e\[[^\]]*\]/i, "")
```

There is no need to match what is before or after with `.*`

The second problem is that you use `.*` to describe the content between brackets. Since the `*` quantifier is by default greedy, it will match all until the last closing bracket in the same line.

To prevent this behaviour a way is to use a negated character class in place of the dot that excludes the closing square brackets `[^\]]`. In this way you keep the advantage of using a greedy quantifier.

Comment: You have to replace `\\e` with `\e` to make it work.

Comment: @toro2k: absolutely not, when you want to write a literal backslash in a pattern, you need to escape it.

Comment: @toro2k: You don't have to do it if you enclose the original string with single quotes.

Comment: Casimir, please elaborate your last sentence; i.e., why is `[^\]]*` preferable to `.*?` ?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: by nature, the walk of a non-greedy/lazy quantifier is slower because for each characters it grabs, it must test before if the next subpattern matches the following text or not. The behaviour of a greedy quantifier is different. It takes all the characters it can, and after it asks questions *(and gives characters back one by one when necessary, this mechanism is called "the backtracking")*. It must only test what characters it grabs. But if you use a negated character class like `[^\]]*` followed by a literal `]`, you can be sure that there is no bactracking phase.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Note that a backtracking step is at least as slow as a non-greedy quantifier step since the regex engine must test the next subpattern too for each character the greedy quantifier gives back.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I hadn't thought much about regex efficiency. Interesting. btw, +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) can do the global matching for you.

```
re = /\\e\[.+?\]/i
'This is an example\e[213] text\e[123] for demonstration'.gsub re, ''
=> "This is an example text for demonstration"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the search less greedy by using `.+?` in the regex

```
puts 'This is an example\e[213] text\e[123] for demonstration'.gsub(/\\e\[.+?\]/, '')  
This is an example text for demonstration  
=> nil
```